# Default contacts app opened instead of my modified Contacts application

Tags: android, contacts

I modified the contacts application(android 4.0.3 source), installed it on my phone (android 4.0.3) and then opened it. However when I selected a contact item, the phone called the contacts details automatically instead of the code modified by myself. why? does it Associate with android:taskAffinity? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the intent is handled by your modified app, specify the package name in the intent. Or use a chooser.

Comment: Original: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactLookupUri）

Comment: I modified: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactLookupUri,PeopleActivity.this,ContactDetailActivityYiui.class);  Thanks again!